# integer is not getting typecasted to bool in c++

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-or, typecasting-operator

While coding, I encountered runtime error. This is my code:

```
int f(int a[],int n,int sum)
{
    int dp[sum+1][n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    dp[0][i]=1;

    for(int i=1;i<=sum;i++)
    dp[i][0]=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=sum;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-1];
            if(i>=a[j-1])
            dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j])^(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1]);
        }
    }

    return dp[sum][n];
}
```

Here sum is always positive. After a lot of debugging I could not get answer So after matching my answer from solution. This is the answer.

```
bool f(int a[],int n,int sum)
{
    bool dp[sum+1][n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    dp[0][i]=true;

    for(int i=1;i<=sum;i++)
    dp[i][0]=false;

    for(int i=1;i<=sum;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-1];
            if(i>=a[j-1])
            dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j])||(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1]);
        }
    }

    return dp[sum][n];
}
```

So my question is why int cannot be converted to bool. 
P.S. : Instead of || I also tried | as this is bitwise operator but still I get runtime error. Someone please help me get the answer.

Comment: The C++ bool has two value `true` and `false` mapping on `1` and `0`.

Comment: why do you expect a cast to `bool`? The operator `^` does not expect a `bool`

Comment: Please describe what this function actually should do.

Comment: The runtime error is probably caused by something else than typecasting (which is compile time), possibly out of bounds access to the array. Also note that `(dp[i][j])^(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1])` (binary XOR) is not equivalent to `(dp[i][j])||(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1])` (logical OR, or even a binary OR for that matter). If you want to use the values as bools and want a logical XOR, you can also do `(dp[i][j]) != (dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1])`.

Comment: There are no casts in this code. The question is about **conversion**.

Comment: Runtime error is not due to memory access as same code runs fine when return type is bool but fails when it is int. So that makes me believe runtime error is in this line of code:
dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j])||(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1]);
So please help me understand why is this piece of code throwing runtime error when return tyoe is int and is working fine in case of bool as return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of the runtime error seems to be the line

```
dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j])^(dp[i-a[j-1]][j-1]);
```

And most likely the `dp[i-a[j-1]]`, which gets the index depending on the value in the `a` array. This can easily result in `dp` being indexed by a negative value.

This suspicion is also backed by the fact that it "works" with `||` (logical or) but does not work with either `^` or `|` (binary operators). This is because the logical operators have short-circuit evaluation (if the `dp[i][j]` is true, the second operator does not need and is not evaluated at all), whereas the binary operators always evaluate both operands.

So it seems that in the case of `||` the second operand is not evaluated thus it does not crash, whereas with the binary operators it is evaluated and the index goes out of bounds and crashes the app.

Comment: Actually, runtime error is coming ehenevr return type is int, no maater which operator do i use, be it | or || or ^, but the same code runs fine if return type is bool. So my que was why is this happening?

Comment: That is strange. Can you re-test in the version returning `bool`, that if you use `^` or `|` on the mentioned line, that it really doesn't crash?